# Django filter ManyToMany relationship from a single object

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, relationship

I've got an object in Django, and one of it's properties is a ManyToMany relationship. 
Ok, now I've got the object, and want to know if there's data related, how can I do it?

Here's the code:

```
u = request.user
ide = request.POST['id']
defob = DefObjc.objects.get(id=ide)
if defob.filter(student_def=u).exists():
  #do things
```

And here's the object class:

```
class DefObjc(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
  date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
  student_def = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='DefObjc_relation', blank=True, null=True)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `get()` is a model instance, not a `QuerySet`, so you can't filter on it. Instead:

```
if defob.student_def.filter(id=u.id).exists():
    # do things
```